# React useeffect, callback function no response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, autodesk-forge

I am trying to setState value from a callback function the problem is that the return `BIM7AATypeComments` sometimes is undefined but if I refresh the page it will add value to setState.
I am not sure if I should use `new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{})`
however, I am using useEffect to fire the function.
thanks!

```js
//Get All Leavs Props
export const getAllLeavesProperties = (
  allModels: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D | undefined,
  cb?
) => {
  const allLoadedViewers = isolateAndColorObject(
    allModels as Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D
  );
  return getAllLeavesDbId(allModels, (dbId: number[]) => {
    const count = dbId.length;
    dbId.forEach((id) => {
      if (allLoadedViewers && id) {
        for (let model of allLoadedViewers) {
          if (model)
            model.getProperties(id, (props) => {
              for (let prop of props.properties) {
                if (!prop) return;

                if (!histogram[prop.displayName]) {
                  histogram[prop.displayName] = {};
                }

                if (!histogram[prop.displayName][prop.displayValue]) {
                  histogram[prop.displayName][prop.displayValue] = [];
                }

                histogram[prop.displayName][prop.displayValue].push(props.dbId);
              }
            });
        }
      }
    });

    cb(histogram);
  });
};


const test = () => {
    if (!allModels) return;
    else {
      getAllLeavesProperties(allModels, (data: any[]) => { //callback 
        if (!data) return;
        //@ts-ignore
        const BIM7AATypeComments = data["BIM7AATypeComments"];
        if (BIM7AATypeComments) {
          try {
            //@ts-ignore
            const modelData = data["BIM7AATypeComments"];
            const label = Object.keys(modelData);

            console.log(label);
            if (label) setTt(label);
            //@ts-ignore
            const myObject = Object.keys(data["BIM7AATypeComments"]).map(
              //@ts-ignore
              (key) => data["BIM7AATypeComments"][key].length
            );
            if (myObject) setrr(myObject);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
  
/*
  React.useEffect(() => {
    test();
  }, []);
  
*/
```

Comment: What do you mean by " return sometimes is undefined " ?

Comment: no response, it's a big JSON object, data["BIM7AATypeComments"] is undefined

Comment: That looks like it might be problem in the `getAllLeavesProperties` . Could you share the implementation of that?

Comment: i have added with previous code!

Comment: if `data["BIM7AATypeComments"]` can produce `undefined`, then no code changes here are going to alter that. If that is what the API returns, then you need to investigate why that happens and make fixes in the API itself (or have someone else make those fixes for you).